# Como fazer o loop esperar o carregamento do 'webbrowser' componente antes de ir pro próximo item?

Tags: vb.net

Estou lendo o conteúdo de uma textbox, e usando um "loop for each" para passar as string em sequencia para a url em localhost que contém o código php:

```
$var = $_GET["nts"];
echo $var;
```

Até aqui está tudo bem, o problema é que o loop não espera pelo carregamento completo do documento webbrowser, dessa forma, por exemplo, eu não consigo fazer um parse no documento html de cada string, a ideia é lançar uma string no webbrowser e esperar pelo carregamento completo do documento webbrowser, para lançar a segunda string e assim sucessivamente.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tb As String = TextBox1.Text
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb) Then
        MsgBox("Null")
    Else
        For Each t As String In tb
            If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)) Then
            Else
                WebBrowser1.Navigate(String.Concat("http://localhost/a/as.php?nts=", t))
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi o problema está em

```
Dim tb As String = TextBox1.Text
```

pois isso vai pegar apenas uma string q seria a TextBox1.Text, e assim fazendo com que só envie uma solicitação com o texto completo da TextBox1, um método simples para resolver isso seria usando

```
Dim tb As String() = Split(TextBox1.Text, " ")
```

Assim separaria cada palavra nos espaços e assim permitindo que se envie varias solicitações com cada palavra do TextBox.

Se o problema continuar comente aqui.